# Semantic React Dropdown with search prop prevents styling

Tags: semantic-ui-react

I'm changing the color of a dropdown's caret with

```
.myclass .ui.dropdown {
    color:transparent!important;
}
```

This hides the caret, as expected, however not when I send the prop 'search' to the Dropdown component.

Has anyone faced this?

I've tried these alternatives

```
.myclass .ui.dropdown.search
.myclass .ui.search.dropdown
.myclass .ui.search
```

I also need to change it this way, rather than with icon=null, because I want to show the caret on hover with

```
.myclass .ui.dropdown:hover {
    color: white!important;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question, shouldn't have given up so quickly. Leaving the post up for others:

SOLUTION:

```
.myclass .ui.dropdown i {
    color:transparent!important;
}
.myclass .ui.dropdown:hover i {
    color:white!important;
}
```

Although this doesn't explain why the search prop changes things, it works.